# How to find if color exists in an image

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am new to open cv and trying to find detect if green color exists in my image or not.

I have the upper color bound and lower color bound in my cv2.range. When I just open with cv2.bitwise_and see the color it shows that there is green color but I don't know how to print if green exist or not

```
hsv_image= cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lg = np.array([56,255,251])        
ug = np.array([60,255,255])

gmask = cv2.inRange(hsv_image,lg ,ug)
color = cv2.bitwise_and(img,img,mask=gmask)


if gmask.equals(img):
    print("green exist")
else: 
    print("not found")
```

I expect to see as the output green exist in a given image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`cv2.countNonZero()`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#countnonzero) on the masked image. Since `cv2.inRange()` returns a binary mask of all pixels within your minimum/maximum color threshold, the idea is that if there is at least one white pixel on the mask then the color exists

```
pixels = cv2.countNonZero(gmask)
if pixels > 0:
    print("green exist")
else: 
    print("not found")
```